# Unable to Create File

Tags: java, android

I am passing a value from android to java file via Intent. The value is getting passed. WHen I write system.out.print, the value is displayed in log cat, but when i try to write in the file, the file does not get created. I donot get any error but nothing is displayed. I tried to changed the location of file, still not working. I have right to keep txt file anywhere though i doble checked it and changed the location also.

Code:

```
            Intent i= new Intent(context, JavaServiceClass.class);
            i.putExtra("stock_list", temparr);
            context.startService(i);
```

JavaServiceClass.java

```
 public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

                ArrayList<String> stock_list = (ArrayList<String>) intent.getExtras().get("stock_list");            
            //  System.out.println(stock_list.get(1) );

                writeInFile(stock_list.get(1));
}
```

If, I do system.out.println, value is diplayed in log cat

```
 public void writeInFile(String stock_list )
            {
                File file = new File("F:/abc.txt");

                if (!file.exists()) {
                    try {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                try {

                    BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));

                    //for (int i1=0;i1<stock_list.length();i1++) {
                        bw.append(stock_list.toString());
                        bw.write("\t");
                    //}             
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Log Cat Warnings :

```
java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
 java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:940)
com.example.wifisignalstrength.JavaServiceClass.writeInFile(JavaServiceClass.java:100)
com.example.wifisignalstrength.JavaServiceClass.onStart(JavaServiceClass.java:42)
android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:438)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2373)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:128)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1224)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
 libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
```

Comment: Have you got this in your AndroidManifest.xml file?

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: " ENOENT (No such file or directory)" <-- are you sure all the parent directories up to and including the immediate parent of the file exist? (also, `F:` on _Android_?)

Comment: @fge I am tryng to save it on my laptop.

Comment: @esdebon Yes, I have written

Comment: Wait, you're trying to write to your laptop from an Android app on your phone?

Comment: You cannot access to your diskdrive .. you can only create a file or a folder in internal storage of your phone /emulator

Comment: BTW, I heard first time that intent can fly from your android device to laptop:D You are must using android emulator and trying to access your hard drive from that. It is going to work. You need to use internal storage or sd card of emulator.

Comment: @JustinJasmann I pass value from android to java desktop server. Now, From java server i am trying to save it in the laptop.. Is it possible ?

Comment: @Adnan I pass value from android to java desktop server. Now, From java server i am trying to save it in the laptop.. Is it possible ?

Comment: @user3345483 That's possible, with a web service or some other design, but not directly.

Comment: Yes it is but through a server. Not by passing by intent.Intent does not go outside of your android app

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a file with a Windows path at the F drive:

```
File file = new File("F:/abc.txt");
```

This file will never exists and can never be created, Android is Linux. Have a look at the Context class (which is extended by the Activity, Service classes) for creating files in internal/external storage of the device. For example, to create the file in the cache directory:

```
File file = new File(getCacheDir(), "abc.txt");
```

Also you need to close your writer in a finally block, and you should handle the exceptions properly too.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.

```
public void writeInFile(String stock_list ) throws Exception
            {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "abc.txt");
    file.createNewFile();

    //write the data into file
    if(file.exists())
    {
         OutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);              
         fo.write(stock_list);
         fo.close();
         System.out.println("file created: "+file);

    }               

   }
```

Do not forget to add following line into manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```